# intellij is there a way to run multiple Junit tests at once right after a maven project is built?

Tags: java, junit, junit5, intellij-14, junit-jupiter

For example, I have a class of Junit tests which inlcudes 100 tests. is there a way to automatically run all these tests right after I build the project? Is there any setting that I need to toggle on and off or any annotations I need to add to my test class to trigger that? 
My current setting is below: it doesn't automatically run the test upon build

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.*;


import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertFalse;

@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
public class someTest {
    @Test
    @Order(1)
    public void Test44(){

   }
    etc...
}
```

Comment: Running tests is usually part of the build. How do you build?

Comment: @johanneslink sorry for the late reply-- > in Intellig, Build -> build project. But my tests are not run automatically, is there anything that I need to do? (Added current test setting)

Comment: In IntelliJ, try pressing Ctrl+Shift+A and then run this command "mvn clean package"

Comment: @VasanthSubramanian thank you! It seems the maven recognize these tests. But I'm not sure why "Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.001 sec" even though there are some tests in it?

Answer (score 0):

In IntelliJ you usually do it the other way round: You run all tests, which will trigger a re-build if required, ie if there are code or config changes that should trigger a rebuild.

IntelliJ chooses the build actions depending on you project’s build tool, e.g. Maven or Gradle.